# Python c extension not loading

Tags: python, c, windows, importerror

A couple of years ago I wrote a c extension to wrap our company's C SDK in Python.  It was done in Windows 10 with Visual C++ 2015 and Python 3.9 and `numpy`.  It worked and I tested it with older versions of python 3 and everything was fine. I just tried the same extension (source code hasn't changed) on Windows 10 with python 3.11 and I'm getting `ImportError: DLL load filed while importing PyGage: The specified module could not be found.` This has happened on 3 seperate computers and with different versions of Python.

I've checked the dependencies with Dependency Walker and dependencies, both say nothing is missing.  I've recompiled the extension with both Visual C++ 2015 and 2017. I've install the Visual C runtimes for VC 2015 and 2017.  I've tried compiling and installing with `setup.py`.  Nothing seems to work. The strange thing is that is does work on some computers, and on the computers where doesn't work, the original extension still works with Anaconda python 3.9.7. The only common thing I can think of on the computers where it doesn't work is they all recently had Visual Studio 2022 installed, though removing it didn't seem to make a difference. Any ideas on how to fix this, or on how to figure out which module is not being found.

Comment: You could use Process Monitor to see what's happening at the system call (e.g. file open, close) level.

Comment: Is PyGage the name of the extension itself, or some dependent module?

Comment: It's the name of the extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, with some help from Jonathon's suggestion. Process Monitor showed me that our SDK DLL wasn't being found, even though the path the DLL was in the right place, in a directory on the path. So I downloaded the Python code, compiled it in debug mode and put breakpoints on all calls to LoadLibrary to see which one failed. The call  that loaded the c extension uses an altered search path (LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR) which, if I understand the docs correctly, does not use the search path.  It uses PYTHONPATH instead for the extension and it's dependencies. So putting the SDK DLLs somewhere on PYTHONPATH works. Still not sure why it worked in python 3.9.7 because the code seems to be the same.